what is the difference between a++ and ++a?
i write this code in c#:
int a = 5, b = 7;
Console.Write(a++ + b - a*b-a++)

okay in this case i was thinking the result must be -29 but result is -36 why?? :
Can someone give a complete explanation why this is so

This is obviously a dupe (notwithstanding the question above answers for C). Please search existing questions before posting new ones. For future reference, please tag only the language you are actually using.

@pierpy I'd guess the execution order might be more relevant for this question. Also please note that in the posted code there are no preincrements.

@rob as @Bob mentioned, the actual point here is the execution-order. The titlge of this question is misleading, as there's no ++a in the question.

I'm not sure why you expected -29, but given that you also originally tagged the question as C (despite the code), here are some anecdotical results: https://godbolt.org/z/snx45o3an and some info: Why are these constructs using pre and post-increment undefined behavior?

Please never write code like this in any production system. I don't think most people have all the order of operations memorized. It would be much more readable if split into multiple lines.

Well, a++ increments a, but returns its "old" value. So the first a++ returns 5, but a has the value 6. Afterwards you add 7 to the "old" value, which returns 12. Now a * b  is calculated. Remember we inremented a already, so it holds the value 6. So we do 12 - 6 * 7. The final a++ is pointless, as the increment happens after everything is done. So although a now is 7, a++ returns the "old" value again, which is 6 at this point.
Afterall, 12 - 42 - 6 equals -36.
